# Read ASCII and UNICODE chars from pipe to char[] in WIN1250 or as wchar_t[]

Tags: c++, unicode, pipe, ascii, readfile

I `CreateProcess` a child app. After execute I can read from pipe attached to out of child process. i have some code to read this:

```
 char chBuf[BUFSIZE];
 DWORD dwRead;

 ReadFile( g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL);
```

Ofc this is simple code without any security checks etc. Only my problem. And when I read, some chars is normal, like normal ANSI char, but when read some regional chars this char is i think in multibyte. Please see screen.

[image]

How can I convert this mix of ASCII and UNICODE array of chars to array of char in WIN1250, or as some array of unicode char like wchar_t[] ?

Comment: That looks like UTF-8, not ‘a mix of ASCII and Unicode’.

Comment: You shove *bytes* through a pipe, what they represent is up to you.  In this  case it appears to be an utf8 encoded string.  Which is fine, quite a common encoding, but don't let that be accidentally fine.  It is UNICODE, not ASCII.  Convert if necessary with, say, MultibyteToWideChar() with CP_UTF8.

Comment: How can I convert this array of butes to some UnicodeString in C++ Builder in easy way?

Comment: @lgabryel In C++Builder 2009+, put the bytes into a [`UTF8String`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.UTF8String) and assign it to a [`UnicodeString`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.UnicodeString), the RTL will convert the data for you. In earlier versions, put the bytes into an [`AnsiString`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.AnsiString), pass it to [`UTF8Decode()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.UTF8Decode), and assign the result to a [`WideString`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.WideString).

Answer (score 1):

@Hans Passant has right. This is solution

```
 char chBuf[BUFSIZE];
 wchar_t wChBuf[BUFSIZE];
 DWORD dwRead;

 ReadFile( g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL);
 MultiByteToWideChar( CP_UTF8, MB_PRECOMPOSED, chBuf, BUFSIZE, wChBuf, ARRAYSIZE(wChBuf));
 UnicodeString str = UnicodeString(wChBuf);
```

[image]

Thank you for help.

Comment: You should be using `dwRead` instead of `BUFSIZE` when calling `MultiByteToWideChar()`. Also, this code does not ensure `wChBuf` is null-terminated, so you should pass the return value of `MultiByteToWideChar()` to the `UnicodeString` constructor. Also, note that UTF-8 uses multi-byte characters, and `ReadFile()` will not guarantee that the end of `chBuf` does not fall in the middle of a byte sequence for an incomplete character (ie, if the last byte in `chBuf` is `0xC4` for a character sequence `0xC4 0x99`), so you should account for that, too.